# Hyperledger fabric channel creation error - unknown consortium name

Tags: docker-compose, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I've been following the `byfn` network tutorial from `hyperledger-fabric v1.4.4` and adapting it so that it has only a single organisation with a single orderer (however my idea is to not have a solo orderer but a etcdraft orderer type) and two peers so far.

I can generate the certificates and artifacts and then start the network (using `docker-compose -f docker-compose-cli.yaml up`) without any errors, using the commands provided in the tutorial (I've changed some peer names and orderer names from the tutorial to fit my project), however when trying to create my first channel with the command `peer channel create -o orderer.trading.com:7050 -c trading-channel -f ./channel-artifacts/channel.tx --tls --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/trading.com/orderers/orderer.trading.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.trading.com-cert.pem`, I get the following error: `Error: got unexpected status: BAD_REQUEST -- Unknown consortium name: TradingConsortium` I've checked the channel-artifacts genesis.block and channel.tx and both have reference of the consortium.

It is also defined under the profiles of the configtx.yaml file as shown below.

What could it be and how would I go about debugging this?

```
# Copyright IBM Corp. All Rights Reserved.
#
# SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
#

---
################################################################################
#
#   Section: Organizations
#
#   - This section defines the different organizational identities which will
#   be referenced later in the configuration.
#
################################################################################
Organizations:

    # SampleOrg defines an MSP using the sampleconfig.  It should never be used
    # in production but may be used as a template for other definitions
    - &OrdererOrg
        # DefaultOrg defines the organization which is used in the sampleconfig
        # of the fabric.git development environment
        Name: OrdererOrg

        # ID to load the MSP definition as
        ID: OrdererMSP

        # MSPDir is the filesystem path which contains the MSP configuration
        MSPDir: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/trading.com/msp

        # Policies defines the set of policies at this level of the config tree
        # For organization policies, their canonical path is usually
        #   /Channel/<Application|Orderer>/<OrgName>/<PolicyName>
        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.member')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.member')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.admin')"

    - &OrgTrader
        # DefaultOrg defines the organization which is used in the sampleconfig
        # of the fabric.git development environment
        Name: OrgTraderMSP

        # ID to load the MSP definition as
        ID: OrgTraderMSP

        MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/orgtrader.trading.com/msp

        # Policies defines the set of policies at this level of the config tree
        # For organization policies, their canonical path is usually
        #   /Channel/<Application|Orderer>/<OrgName>/<PolicyName>
        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('OrgTraderMSP.admin', 'OrgTraderMSP.peer', 'OrgTraderMSP.client')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('OrgTraderMSP.admin', 'OrgTraderMSP.client')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('OrgTraderMSP.admin')"
            Endorsement:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('OrgTraderMSP.peer')"

        # leave this flag set to true.
        AnchorPeers:
            # AnchorPeers defines the location of peers which can be used
            # for cross org gossip communication.  Note, this value is only
            # encoded in the genesis block in the Application section context
            - Host: peer0.orgtrader.trading.com
              Port: 7051

################################################################################
#
#   SECTION: Capabilities
#
#   - This section defines the capabilities of fabric network. This is a new
#   concept as of v1.1.0 and should not be utilized in mixed networks with
#   v1.0.x peers and orderers.  Capabilities define features which must be
#   present in a fabric binary for that binary to safely participate in the
#   fabric network.  For instance, if a new MSP type is added, newer binaries
#   might recognize and validate the signatures from this type, while older
#   binaries without this support would be unable to validate those
#   transactions.  This could lead to different versions of the fabric binaries
#   having different world states.  Instead, defining a capability for a channel
#   informs those binaries without this capability that they must cease
#   processing transactions until they have been upgraded.  For v1.0.x if any
#   capabilities are defined (including a map with all capabilities turned off)
#   then the v1.0.x peer will deliberately crash.
#
################################################################################
Capabilities:
    # Channel capabilities apply to both the orderers and the peers and must be
    # supported by both.
    # Set the value of the capability to true to require it.
    Channel: &ChannelCapabilities
        # V2_0 capability ensures that orderers and peers behave according
        # to v2.0 channel capabilities. Orderers and peers from
        # prior releases would behave in an incompatible way, and are therefore
        # not able to participate in channels at v2.0 capability.
        # Prior to enabling V2.0 channel capabilities, ensure that all
        # orderers and peers on a channel are at v2.0.0 or later.
        V2_0: true

    # Orderer capabilities apply only to the orderers, and may be safely
    # used with prior release peers.
    # Set the value of the capability to true to require it.
    Orderer: &OrdererCapabilities
        # V2_0 orderer capability ensures that orderers behave according
        # to v2.0 orderer capabilities. Orderers from
        # prior releases would behave in an incompatible way, and are therefore
        # not able to participate in channels at v2.0 orderer capability.
        # Prior to enabling V2.0 orderer capabilities, ensure that all
        # orderers on channel are at v2.0.0 or later.
        V2_0: true

    # Application capabilities apply only to the peer network, and may be safely
    # used with prior release orderers.
    # Set the value of the capability to true to require it.
    Application: &ApplicationCapabilities
        # V2_0 application capability ensures that peers behave according
        # to v2.0 application capabilities. Peers from
        # prior releases would behave in an incompatible way, and are therefore
        # not able to participate in channels at v2.0 application capability.
        # Prior to enabling V2.0 application capabilities, ensure that all
        # peers on channel are at v2.0.0 or later.
        V2_0: true

################################################################################
#
#   SECTION: Application
#
#   - This section defines the values to encode into a config transaction or
#   genesis block for application related parameters
#
################################################################################
Application: &ApplicationDefaults

    # Organizations is the list of orgs which are defined as participants on
    # the application side of the network
    Organizations:

    # Policies defines the set of policies at this level of the config tree
    # For Application policies, their canonical path is
    #   /Channel/Application/<PolicyName>
    Policies:
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"
        LifecycleEndorsement:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Endorsement"
        Endorsement:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Endorsement"

    Capabilities:
        <<: *ApplicationCapabilities
################################################################################
#
#   SECTION: Orderer
#
#   - This section defines the values to encode into a config transaction or
#   genesis block for orderer related parameters
#
################################################################################
Orderer: &OrdererDefaults

    # Orderer Type: The orderer implementation to start
    OrdererType: etcdraft

    Addresses:
        - orderer.trading.com:7050

    # Batch Timeout: The amount of time to wait before creating a batch
    BatchTimeout: 2s

    # Batch Size: Controls the number of messages batched into a block
    BatchSize:

        # Max Message Count: The maximum number of messages to permit in a batch
        MaxMessageCount: 10

        # Absolute Max Bytes: The absolute maximum number of bytes allowed for
        # the serialized messages in a batch.
        AbsoluteMaxBytes: 99 MB

        # Preferred Max Bytes: The preferred maximum number of bytes allowed for
        # the serialized messages in a batch. A message larger than the preferred
        # max bytes will result in a batch larger than preferred max bytes.
        PreferredMaxBytes: 512 KB

    # Organizations is the list of orgs which are defined as participants on
    # the orderer side of the network
    Organizations:

    # Policies defines the set of policies at this level of the config tree
    # For Orderer policies, their canonical path is
    #   /Channel/Orderer/<PolicyName>
    Policies:
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"
        # BlockValidation specifies what signatures must be included in the block
        # from the orderer for the peer to validate it.
        BlockValidation:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"

################################################################################
#
#   CHANNEL
#
#   This section defines the values to encode into a config transaction or
#   genesis block for channel related parameters.
#
################################################################################
Channel: &ChannelDefaults
    # Policies defines the set of policies at this level of the config tree
    # For Channel policies, their canonical path is
    #   /Channel/<PolicyName>
    Policies:
        # Who may invoke the 'Deliver' API
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        # Who may invoke the 'Broadcast' API
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        # By default, who may modify elements at this config level
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"

    # Capabilities describes the channel level capabilities, see the
    # dedicated Capabilities section elsewhere in this file for a full
    # description
    Capabilities:
        <<: *ChannelCapabilities

################################################################################
#
#   Profile
#
#   - Different configuration profiles may be encoded here to be specified
#   as parameters to the configtxgen tool
#
################################################################################
Profiles:

    ChemartOrgsChannel:
        Consortium: TradingConsortium
        <<: *ChannelDefaults
        Application:
            <<: *ApplicationDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *OrgTrader
            Capabilities:
                <<: *ApplicationCapabilities

    MultiNodeEtcdRaft:
        <<: *ChannelDefaults
        Capabilities:
            <<: *ChannelCapabilities
        Orderer:
            <<: *OrdererDefaults
            OrdererType: etcdraft
            EtcdRaft:
                Consenters:
                    - Host: orderer.trading.com
                      Port: 7050
                      ClientTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/trading.com/orderers/orderer.trading.com/tls/server.crt
                      ServerTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/trading.com/orderers/orderer.trading.com/tls/server.crt
            Addresses:
                - orderer.trading.com:7050
            Organizations:
            - *OrdererOrg
            Capabilities:
                <<: *OrdererCapabilities
        Application:
            <<: *ApplicationDefaults
            Organizations:
            - <<: *OrdererOrg
        Consortiums:
            TradingConsortium:
                Organizations:
                - *OrgTrader
```

This is my crypto-config.yaml file:

```
# Copyright IBM Corp. All Rights Reserved.
#
# SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
#

# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# "OrdererOrgs" - Definition of organizations managing orderer nodes
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OrdererOrgs:
  # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # Orderer
  # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  - Name: Orderer
    Domain: trading.com
    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # "Specs" - See PeerOrgs below for complete description
    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Specs:
      - Hostname: orderer

# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# "PeerOrgs" - Definition of organizations managing peer nodes
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
PeerOrgs:
  # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # OrgTrader
  # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  - Name: OrgTrader
    Domain: orgtrader.trading.com
    EnableNodeOUs: true
    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # "Specs"
    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Uncomment this section to enable the explicit definition of hosts in your
    # configuration.  Most users will want to use Template, below
    #
    # Specs is an array of Spec entries.  Each Spec entry consists of two fields:
    #   - Hostname:   (Required) The desired hostname, sans the domain.
    #   - CommonName: (Optional) Specifies the template or explicit override for
    #                 the CN.  By default, this is the template:
    #
    #                              "{{.Hostname}}.{{.Domain}}"
    #
    #                 which obtains its values from the Spec.Hostname and
    #                 Org.Domain, respectively.
    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Specs:
    #   - Hostname: foo # implicitly "foo.orgtrader.trading.com"
    #     CommonName: foo27.org5.trading.com # overrides Hostname-based FQDN set above
    #   - Hostname: bar
    #   - Hostname: baz
    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # "Template"
    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Allows for the definition of 1 or more hosts that are created sequentially
    # from a template. By default, this looks like "peer%d" from 0 to Count-1.
    # You may override the number of nodes (Count), the starting index (Start)
    # or the template used to construct the name (Hostname).
    #
    # Note: Template and Specs are not mutually exclusive.  You may define both
    # sections and the aggregate nodes will be created for you.  Take care with
    # name collisions
    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Template:
      Count: 2
      # Start: 5
      # Hostname: {{.Prefix}}{{.Index}} # default
    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # "Users"
    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Count: The number of user accounts _in addition_ to Admin
    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Users:
      Count: 1
```

Comment: which profile you are using to generate genesis block and channel file ?

Comment: The MultiNodeEtcdRaft profile for the Genesis block and the ChemartOrgsChannel for the channel file

Comment: I just recreated everything from scratch using the fabric sample byfn and it's working again.